# Have any option in salesforce to check the email send or not (Expect Email Logs)

Tags: email, history-tracking, status

Is there any option in Salesforce to check the email send or not (Expect Email Logs)

i want track my mail send or not in case object please give any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain the scenario where you want to check the status of your email?

As per my knowledge Email Logs is the only option where you check the status of email.Another option is Bounce email but you need to activate bounce management first.If you are a receiver and somehow your email is getting bounced then you will receive bounce email notification from Salesforce.
If you are using HTML Email then following link will help you to track Email through Salesforce.com.

http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/tracking-html-email-salesforce/

Comment: yes i am already using Bounce email, but business requirement was,once email receive  to customer,automatic status filed change 'Email delivery',if could not send,status will changed 'not delivery' @Dhanajay Patil